# Joint Gaussian distribution implies Gaussian + independence?

Tags: random-variables, independence, gaussian

Assume that $X = (X_1, ... , X_n)$ are **jointly Gaussian distributed**.

Can I then say that each of $X_1, ... , X_n$ is **Gaussian** distributed?

Can I deduce that they are pairwise **independent**?

Comment: Yes, each of them is Gaussian. However, you cannot say they are independent, since dependent random variables can have jointly Gaussian distributed as well. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution, for further explanation about the role of covariance Matrix, in the distribution.

Comment: Gaussian+independence implies joint Gaussian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been noted, the marginal distribution of each $X_i$ will be Gaussian. But the $X_i$ are independent iff they're uncorrelated. This is a very convenient result, but it does require the joint distribution to be multivariate Gaussian; [it doesn't follow from the marginal distributions being Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent).

Answer (score 1):

If random vector $\vec X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)^T$ has normal distribution then $A\vec X$ has normal distribution (here $A$ denotes $m\times n$-matrix with entries in $\mathbb R$).

Applying that with $A=A^{1\times n}=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ we find that the $X_i$ have normal distribution.

The $X_i$ are not necessarily independent.